# probabilities for obtaining 3 dice result

Tags: random, dice

I am developing an app that needs a 3 dice result and there are two methods I can use:

> **method a)** *create a matrix of 216 possible combinations and choose 1
>   randomly*
>
> **method b)** *or generate 3 dice results separately*

I am not a math pro but for instance for a result of 3 (1-1-1) is there any difference in chances/probabilities between these two methods ?

Which one is preferable?

Comment: Which programming language are you using to build the app? Do you need all the information from the 3 dice throws, or just some aspect of it (e.g. the sum of the results of the three dice)?

Comment: that's exactly the same thing. numerical/time efficiency depends on your algorithm, but as to probability issues there's no difference

Comment: Bhoot, PHP. I need to get each value of 3 dice in one call that's why I am adopting method a. mm-aops all right thanks :) I just need to hear from the pros.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is: Does generating three numbers each using `Int(Rnd(6)+1)` have a significantly different distribution to looking up an indexed array of all the possible triplets with `Int(Rnd(216)`?

It should not.

There is a very minor saving in computation time in doing one calculation and lookup verses doing three calculation.  On the other hand there is the overhead of populating and storing the global array.  So I'd advise generating each roll separately as the way to proceed; unless you needed to make a very large number of calls to the generating procedure.

Comment: Thanks Graham. But what do you mean by overhead of populating ? Why exactly youre advising to generate each roll separately if youre saying "should" not have any difference?

Comment: The difference is in program performance rather than probability.  The overhead is the memory allocation and operations needed to fill the array; as well as the additional code needed to do so.  If you're only needing to generate the random result a few times, this is wasted effort.  You only save computing power if you need to generate the results a considerable number of times.  (Even then, I'd argue that the performance saved is not really worth the additional coding complexity.) It's a question of effort versus returns. As a matter of principle, don't do more work than you need to do.

Comment: ok, but the probabilities are the same though ok thanks